# Tab Bar app with a split view controller - the detail page is showing first before the main page

Tags: swift, tabbar, splitview

I have created a Tab Bar App.  On the first item, is a Split View Controller with a Master and Detail.  When running the app, I can see the tab bar on the page however, it's showing my Detail page.  Why is it not defaulting to the Master page?

I have researched some answers but no luck.

```
SplitViewController.swift

import UIKit


class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController,
UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.delegate = self
    self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
}

func splitViewController(
    _ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
    collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
    onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // Return true to prevent UIKit from applying its default behavior
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference in case someone bumps into the same problem.

I had to use my Master-Detail SplitViewController app (without the tab bar) and do the following:

1. Add a Tab Bar Controller.
2. Connect the binding from Tab Bar Controller to the Split View Controller, as a view controller.
3. Revise AppDelegate.swift

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       let tabBarViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
       print(tabBarViewController.viewControllers?.count)
       var splitViewController:UISplitViewController? = nil
       for viewController in tabBarViewController.viewControllers! {
           if viewController.title == "Master" {
               splitViewController = viewController as? UISplitViewController
           }
       }
       return true
   }
   ```
4. Set Tab Bar Controller to be the Initial View Controller.

Hope this helps. Thanks!